# Why am I getting two different sets of values from my Ruby object when using .to_hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

I have an object in my Rails project, and when I do `record.to_hash` I get values, but I'm missing at least one -- notably `experience`.  When I do record.attributes.to_hash I get more options including the attribute `experience`.  Here's my output from using byebug below.  Can anyone explain why this is the case? I was using `record.to_hash` in conjunction with `update_attributes` method to update an object but I need the additional attributes.

```
record.to_hash
#=> {:player_url=>"http://www.unlvrebels.com//sports/m-footbl/mtt/casey_acosta_1024286.html", :headshot_url=>nil, :jersey=>"87", :first_name=>"Casey", :last_name=>"Acosta", :position=>"WR", :height=>"5110", :weight=>"160", :eligibility=>nil, :hometown_city=>"Las Vegas", :hometown_state=>"NV", :high_school=>"Chaparral HS", :biography_text=>nil, :is_basketball_player=>false, :possible_dob=>false, :possible_transfer=>false, :possible_redshirt=>false, :possible_gpa=>false, :possible_track_participant=>false, :possible_basketball_participant=>false, :possible_baseball_participant=>false, :possible_hockey_participant=>false, :possible_lacrosse_participant=>false, :possible_power_lifting_participant=>false, :possible_rugby_participant=>false, :possible_soccer_participant=>false, :possible_volleyball_participant=>false, :possible_wrestling_participant=>false, :possible_medical_alert=>false, :possible_character_alert=>false, :school_id=>664, :player_id=>nil, :position_id=>2}
record.attributes.to_hash
#=> {"id"=>nil, "school_site_id"=>nil, "player_url"=>"http://www.unlvrebels.com//sports/m-footbl/mtt/casey_acosta_1024286.html", "headshot_url"=>nil, "jersey"=>"87", "first_name"=>"Casey", "last_name"=>"Acosta", "position"=>"WR", "height"=>"5110", "weight"=>"160", "eligibility"=>nil, "hometown_city"=>"Las Vegas", "hometown_state"=>"NV", "high_school"=>"Chaparral HS", "major"=>nil, "previous_school"=>nil, "experience"=>"FR", "biography_text"=>nil, "has_relative_in_sports"=>false, "is_basketball_player"=>false, "possible_dob"=>false, "possible_transfer"=>false, "possible_redshirt"=>false, "possible_gpa"=>false, "possible_track_participant"=>false, "possible_basketball_participant"=>false, "possible_baseball_participant"=>false, "possible_hockey_participant"=>false, "possible_lacrosse_participant"=>false, "possible_power_lifting_participant"=>false, "possible_rugby_participant"=>false, "possible_soccer_participant"=>false, "possible_volleyball_participant"=>false, "possible_wrestling_participant"=>false, "possible_medical_alert"=>false, "possible_character_alert"=>false, "school_id"=>664, "player_id"=>nil, "position_id"=>2, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`record` is an instance of `Record` class, whereas `record.attributes` is an instance of `Hash` class.

The difference probably occur because `to_hash` method implemented differently for instances of these two classes.

Comment: So, if I use attributes, that works except that, it includes attributes like `id`.  Is there a more `Rails` way of doing what I'm trying to without removing those attributes through additional code? Wasn't sure if there was a method I should be using.

Comment: @daveomcd `record.attributes` is already a `Hash`, so it *is* what you want :) No need to call `to_hash` on it. `record.attributes == record.attributes.to_hash` => `true`

Comment: Okay thanks, I think this is what I'll use with `update_attributes` -- `record.attributes.except('id','created_at','updated_at')`

Comment: @daveomcd you can, for example, implement a `to_h` method in `Record` model like this: `def to_h; attributes.except('id','created_at','updated_at') end` and use it as `record.to_h`